# Splitting a list into 2 lists by alternating the elements

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to split a list into 2 lists where the elements from the original list are put alternating into the new lists.
Here's a simple example with the expected output.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

=> 
['a', 'c', 'e']
['b', 'd', 'f']
```

I expected an existing solution for this in itertools, but couldn't find anything that fit. I also couldn't find any solution here.
Eventually I went with the following solution. It works good enough, is short/readable, but is not efficient (iterating the original list twice, and using indices instead of iterators).

```
l1 = [l[i] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
l2 = [l[i] for i in range(1, len(l), 2)]
```

Now I'm curious. Is there an existing, generic solution that is both short AND efficient?

Comment: Just use slice notation: `l1, l2 = l[::2], l[1::2]`

Answer (score 1):

You can slice lists with the syntax `l[start:stop:increment]`. So in your case it would be `l[::2]` and `l[1::2]`. If you leave the argument blank, the default values are `0`, `len(l)`, and `1` respectively.